# How can I burn an ISO using C#

Tags: c#, image, iso, dvd-burning

I have no experience in burning cd/dvd through code. could someone point me out where to start or give an example?

Comment: Is that anything in particular that tells you i didn't? i found the link bellow but i didnt know how to import imapi2 and i didnt understand how to do that dll imports. I ve never done it before. So i thought that there might be a "native way" a class may be. so please spare me the minuses and give a helpful answer if you can.

Comment: How is this not a real question? c# in the tag, burn an iso, no experience, give an example of where to start. (+1 to offset some minuses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Burning and Erasing CD/DVD/Blu-ray Media with C# in [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsopticalplatform/thread/90688a47-eff6-4443-b8b8-3b474f066d5e/) and [forums thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsopticalplatform/thread/90688a47-eff6-4443-b8b8-3b474f066d5e/)

you can search in google and you can find more.

I hope these  links will helps  you and how to [install IMAP](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsopticalplatform/thread/90688a47-eff6-4443-b8b8-3b474f066d5e/) and [how](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsopticalplatform/thread/709d5658-6581-4dbc-8357-778cf052afe9/) to [use it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualfoxprogeneral/thread/7d2d5655-bd88-4dcb-b576-d6d72b66e987)

Comment: Please read the above comment. I didn't know i had to report my whole browsing history along with my question. i'm sorry.

Comment: @sparky i have edited my answer pls take a look at this one

Comment: thak you very much this is helpful